# Read iText7 XObject QrCode c#

Tags: c#, itext7

I've been playing with iText7 for a bit and have a question about its FormXObject QrCode generation.

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("C:\\Testing\\Documentation\\Infomercial.pdf");
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf);
iText.Barcodes.BarcodeQRCode qrcode = new BarcodeQRCode("{\"item\":\"123\",\"id\":\"123\"}");
var codeFormObject = qrcode.CreateFormXObject(pdf);
```

What i would like to do now, is read the barcode...when i try to extract the image out of it using code i found on here i cannot seem to get to the image of the barcode.

So option 1 is: to on the fly read the barcode on the pdf if possible
Option2: I suppose i could flatten the pdf page to an image and then use zxing? to read the barcode?

I would like to do option1 rather than 2 but not sure if thats even possible, I've tried to extract the image of the barcode but it seems like it isn't actually an image?

The stream

```
4 28 1 1 re
5 28 1 1 re
6 28 1 1 re
7 28 1 1 re
8 28 1 1 re
9 28 1 1 re
10 28 1 1 re
12 28 1 1 re
14 28 1 1 re
16 28 1 1 re
18 28 1 1 re
20 28 1 1 re
22 28 1 1 re
23 28 1 1 re
24 28 1 1 re
25 28 1 1 re
26 28 1 1 re
27 28 1 1 re
28 28 1 1 re
4 27 1 1 re
10 27 1 1 re
13 27 1 1 re
14 27 1 1 re
15 27 1 1 re
16 27 1 1 re
17 27 1 1 re
18 27 1 1 re
20 27 1 1 re
22 27 1 1 re
28 27 1 1 re
4 26 1 1 re
6 26 1 1 re
7 26 1 1 re
8 26 1 1 re
10 26 1 1 re
12 26 1 1 re
13 26 1 1 re
14 26 1 1 re
17 26 1 1 re
19 26 1 1 re
22 26 1 1 re
24 26 1 1 re
25 26 1 1 re
26 26 1 1 re
28 26 1 1 re
4 25 1 1 re
6 25 1 1 re
7 25 1 1 re
8 25 1 1 re
10 25 1 1 re
12 25 1 1 re
13 25 1 1 re
14 25 1 1 re
16 25 1 1 re
17 25 1 1 re
18 25 1 1 re
22 25 1 1 re
24 25 1 1 re
25 25 1 1 re
26 25 1 1 re
28 25 1 1 re
4 24 1 1 re
6 24 1 1 re
7 24 1 1 re
8 24 1 1 re
10 24 1 1 re
12 24 1 1 re
15 24 1 1 re
16 24 1 1 re
18 24 1 1 re
19 24 1 1 re
20 24 1 1 re
22 24 1 1 re
24 24 1 1 re
25 24 1 1 re
26 24 1 1 re
28 24 1 1 re
4 23 1 1 re
10 23 1 1 re
14 23 1 1 re
15 23 1 1 re
17 23 1 1 re
18 23 1 1 re
22 23 1 1 re
28 23 1 1 re
4 22 1 1 re
5 22 1 1 re
6 22 1 1 re
7 22 1 1 re
8 22 1 1 re
9 22 1 1 re
10 22 1 1 re
12 22 1 1 re
14 22 1 1 re
16 22 1 1 re
18 22 1 1 re
20 22 1 1 re
22 22 1 1 re
23 22 1 1 re
24 22 1 1 re
25 22 1 1 re
26 22 1 1 re
27 22 1 1 re
28 22 1 1 re
14 21 1 1 re
16 21 1 1 re
18 21 1 1 re
19 21 1 1 re
4 20 1 1 re
5 20 1 1 re
6 20 1 1 re
7 20 1 1 re
10 20 1 1 re
12 20 1 1 re
14 20 1 1 re
15 20 1 1 re
20 20 1 1 re
21 20 1 1 re
24 20 1 1 re
25 20 1 1 re
26 20 1 1 re
28 20 1 1 re
7 19 1 1 re
8 19 1 1 re
9 19 1 1 re
14 19 1 1 re
16 19 1 1 re
20 19 1 1 re
21 19 1 1 re
25 19 1 1 re
26 19 1 1 re
4 18 1 1 re
8 18 1 1 re
10 18 1 1 re
12 18 1 1 re
13 18 1 1 re
14 18 1 1 re
15 18 1 1 re
16 18 1 1 re
17 18 1 1 re
18 18 1 1 re
20 18 1 1 re
21 18 1 1 re
25 18 1 1 re
6 17 1 1 re
7 17 1 1 re
8 17 1 1 re
9 17 1 1 re
12 17 1 1 re
13 17 1 1 re
14 17 1 1 re
16 17 1 1 re
17 17 1 1 re
21 17 1 1 re
22 17 1 1 re
23 17 1 1 re
25 17 1 1 re
26 17 1 1 re
28 17 1 1 re
6 16 1 1 re
10 16 1 1 re
13 16 1 1 re
14 16 1 1 re
15 16 1 1 re
17 16 1 1 re
19 16 1 1 re
22 16 1 1 re
23 16 1 1 re
24 16 1 1 re
25 16 1 1 re
26 16 1 1 re
28 16 1 1 re
5 15 1 1 re
6 15 1 1 re
7 15 1 1 re
11 15 1 1 re
16 15 1 1 re
17 15 1 1 re
19 15 1 1 re
20 15 1 1 re
21 15 1 1 re
22 15 1 1 re
24 15 1 1 re
25 15 1 1 re
27 15 1 1 re
28 15 1 1 re
5 14 1 1 re
6 14 1 1 re
9 14 1 1 re
10 14 1 1 re
11 14 1 1 re
12 14 1 1 re
13 14 1 1 re
20 14 1 1 re
26 14 1 1 re
4 13 1 1 re
6 13 1 1 re
8 13 1 1 re
9 13 1 1 re
13 13 1 1 re
15 13 1 1 re
16 13 1 1 re
25 13 1 1 re
27 13 1 1 re
6 12 1 1 re
7 12 1 1 re
8 12 1 1 re
10 12 1 1 re
11 12 1 1 re
13 12 1 1 re
15 12 1 1 re
17 12 1 1 re
18 12 1 1 re
20 12 1 1 re
21 12 1 1 re
22 12 1 1 re
23 12 1 1 re
24 12 1 1 re
26 12 1 1 re
27 12 1 1 re
28 12 1 1 re
12 11 1 1 re
14 11 1 1 re
15 11 1 1 re
17 11 1 1 re
19 11 1 1 re
20 11 1 1 re
24 11 1 1 re
26 11 1 1 re
27 11 1 1 re
28 11 1 1 re
4 10 1 1 re
5 10 1 1 re
6 10 1 1 re
7 10 1 1 re
8 10 1 1 re
9 10 1 1 re
10 10 1 1 re
14 10 1 1 re
17 10 1 1 re
20 10 1 1 re
22 10 1 1 re
24 10 1 1 re
25 10 1 1 re
26 10 1 1 re
27 10 1 1 re
28 10 1 1 re
4 9 1 1 re
10 9 1 1 re
13 9 1 1 re
18 9 1 1 re
19 9 1 1 re
20 9 1 1 re
24 9 1 1 re
28 9 1 1 re
4 8 1 1 re
6 8 1 1 re
7 8 1 1 re
8 8 1 1 re
10 8 1 1 re
14 8 1 1 re
16 8 1 1 re
20 8 1 1 re
21 8 1 1 re
22 8 1 1 re
23 8 1 1 re
24 8 1 1 re
25 8 1 1 re
28 8 1 1 re
4 7 1 1 re
6 7 1 1 re
7 7 1 1 re
8 7 1 1 re
10 7 1 1 re
12 7 1 1 re
14 7 1 1 re
15 7 1 1 re
16 7 1 1 re
18 7 1 1 re
19 7 1 1 re
20 7 1 1 re
22 7 1 1 re
23 7 1 1 re
24 7 1 1 re
25 7 1 1 re
26 7 1 1 re
27 7 1 1 re
28 7 1 1 re
4 6 1 1 re
6 6 1 1 re
7 6 1 1 re
8 6 1 1 re
10 6 1 1 re
12 6 1 1 re
13 6 1 1 re
14 6 1 1 re
15 6 1 1 re
18 6 1 1 re
21 6 1 1 re
22 6 1 1 re
24 6 1 1 re
26 6 1 1 re
27 6 1 1 re
4 5 1 1 re
10 5 1 1 re
12 5 1 1 re
13 5 1 1 re
15 5 1 1 re
17 5 1 1 re
18 5 1 1 re
21 5 1 1 re
22 5 1 1 re
23 5 1 1 re
24 5 1 1 re
26 5 1 1 re
4 4 1 1 re
5 4 1 1 re
6 4 1 1 re
7 4 1 1 re
8 4 1 1 re
9 4 1 1 re
10 4 1 1 re
12 4 1 1 re
17 4 1 1 re
19 4 1 1 re
22 4 1 1 re
25 4 1 1 re
26 4 1 1 re
27 4 1 1 re
28 4 1 1 re
f
```

So are there known libraries that will do the conversion? What would such conversion be called bytes to image? I'm not sure what this stream would be called? or if there is a library that will do the conversion.
Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand what you are really trying. You create a QR code form Xobject object, and then what? You want to extract the information from that Xobject object directly? Or is an actual pdf file content involved?

Answer (score 0):

I am the image of my father, does not imply I am a pixel or vector family representative.

Bar/QR codes should be vector objects and can be generated by using vector fonts or scalable vector graphics.

For convenience they are  sometimes generated as monochrome PNG/TIF/GIF pixel images with integer pixel sizes. Thus a single QR square could be 4x4 pixels. One reason NOT to use Jpeg as it approximates 8x8 pixels at a time producing "halo" artefacts.

To answer your question you either need to convert those image objects to a pixel image or extract as a font or vector image.

Perhaps the generation example description helps to show how simpler 2D barcodes may be constructed see https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/faq/how-to-generate-2d-barcode-as-vector-image

The extraction to reverse a code graphic without tools is exceptionally challenging.

The stream will look like this (corrupted by my cut and paste)

```
1 0 obj <</Type/XObject/Resources<<>>/Subtype/Form/BBox[0 0 86 22]/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]/Length 2063/FormType 1/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream xœUÛKŽìè
„Ñù]E-!ÅçŸr÷üîàLØ(¡'‘hòcªýúy}þùûïŸ×O\?ßþþçÏ…t¢ÝèA/ú-ß—ÔË–ëøC@<...**continues for a while** ... endobj
```

That's not much to go on, or use until its decrypted/decode and expanded into graphics and this one is easier to explain as its a 2D bar code but QR will just be more complex so translated it is 13k for the small high quality vector image
[image]

we can use a tool such as mutool to query the object

`mutool show barcode.pdf 1`

```
1 0 obj
<<
  /Type /XObject
  /Resources <<
  >>
  /Subtype /Form
  /BBox [ 0 0 86 22 ]
  /Matrix [ 1 0 0 1 0 0 ]
  /Length 13178
  /FormType 1
>>
stream
0 0 0 rg
0 21 1 1 re
1 21 1 1 re
2 21 1 1 re
3 21 1 1 re
4 21 1 1 re
5 21 1 1 re
6 21 1 1 re
7 21 1 1 re
9 21 1 1 re
11 21 1 1 re
13 21 1 1 re
17 21 1 1 re
... continues for over 1000 lines of code !
```

So what we can see is a black bar for columns 1-7 then a white space for 8 then black for column 9 11 13 and 17 so 10,12, 14, 15 and 16 are white. Then we get to the more random bit so I will stop boring you here.

For a QR code the sequential blocks of black lines (**re**ctangles) would clearly be much more jumbled.

Clearly different to an expected graphic as its in effect a stack computer language but based loosely on its Father PostScript (full circle to my opening comment) you could try import PDF page into some PS graphics package and attempt clipping that into SVG. Simplest if the QR code is in a fixed location is using a scriptable image app (such as IrfanView etc.) to clip the zone and save as an image, however pixel registration by scaling may generally be offset by sub pixels causing a castellated edge to mono graphics, or anti-aliased edges.
[image]
[image]

With image processing we can get 398 bytes PNG or 5,297 bytes Jpeg which is inferior
[image]

here it may not be noticable but a scanner would have more problems with the lower one, like a camera detector you need to zoom in to see the grey in both the black and white areas.
[image]

Comment: I'm able to get the bytes/stream but not sure how I would turn it into an image. Could you point me in the right direction, i know natively it isn't a png,jpg or any other type of image format. Its an XObject but not sure how to conver the bytes to an image.

Comment: I dont have an issue constructing the qr code. I successfully have it on the pdf now i would like to read the barcode - for clarification.

Comment: what would that library be called that would do this parsing? I have a few functions that turn bytes into images but this seems different.

Comment: So it sounds like, maybe i should switch my approach? Instead of doing a FormXObject i should generate the qr code as a bitmap or some image and then slap that on the pdf?

Comment: I was playing with ghostscript also but i didn't like the fact that i had to install it also...at least thats what it seemed like when i downloaded the nuget pkg. I decided to tackle it a different way..and slap the jpeg image on the pdf..then i can extract the image from the pdf.